# javascript to iterate image folders and add images to an unordered list

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to figure out exactly why this script wont work. I first thought it might be because of the div and the following ul, but it still wont work after assigning an additional ID to the ul. Really need to figure this out tonight, so all help is highly appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<div id="Home-Image">   

    <h1>Images</h1>
    <ul id="Home-Images">
        <li><a href="#"><img src="" width=100 height=100/></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="" width=100 height=100/></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="" width=100 height=100/></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="" width=100 height=100/></a></li>
        <button id="toggle-two">View more Images</button>
    </ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var files = {'jpg':4};
var pageName = "d";
for (var ext in files){
for (var i = 0; i < files[ext]; i++){
var src = "../Images/D/allimages" + pageName + "-" + (i+1) + "." + ext;}
var img = new Image(); 
img.src = src;
var container = document.getElementById('Home-Images');
container.appendChild(img);
}});
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Here's a fiddle of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/PdxAp/ Looks fine to me (except for the images)...

Comment: Rather pointless to append IMG to UL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var files = {'jpg':4}, pageName = "d", container = $('#Home-Images');
    for (var ext in files)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < files[ext]; i++)
        {
            var src = "../Images/D/allimages" + pageName + "-" + (i+1) + "."+ext ;
            var img = $('<img src="'+src+'" width=100 height=100 />'); 
            container.append($('<li/>').html($('<a/>', {'href':'#'}).html(img)));
        }
    }
});
```

But make sure this path `http://yourDomain/Images/D/allimagesd-1.jpg` ​is right for all images.
Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kMfkk/1/) but images are not available but you can see the source by browser inspection tool.

Answer (score 0):

Modified code:[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mfssj/)

HTML:

```
<div id="Home-Image">   

    <h1>Images</h1>
    <ul id="Home-Images">

        <button id="toggle-two">View more Images</button>
    </ul>​
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var files = {'jpg':4};
    var pageName = "d";
    var html = "", src;
for (var ext in files){
     for (var i = 0; i < files[ext]; i++){
         src = "../Images/D/allimages" + pageName + "-" + (i+1) + "." + ext;
         html += '<li><a href="#"><img src="'+ src +'" width=100 height=100/></a></li>';

     }

    $("#Home-Images").prepend(html );
}}); ​
```